# Why is my chart not working? What am I missing

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, chart.js, block

SO I am currently following a tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sE08f4iuOhA
and the guy uses a script in html. I dont want to separate them and created a js file. Seemed easy but its not working. I have no idea what im missing. I have done exactly like him except I moved all the js code to a js file.

here is a link to code.pen: https://codepen.io/julius-88/pen/LYxjByE

Code in js.file

```
let myChart = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
    type: "line",
    data: {},
    options: {
        labels: ["Stockholm", "Göteborg", "Malmö", "Uppsala", "Upplands Väsby"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Population",
            data: [
                1515017,
                599011,
                316588,
                160462,
                144826
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {}
});
```

code in HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chart</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="/chart.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So `chart.js` is your own script, shown in the question in full? If so, you also need to include the Chart.js script, before your own. (at 2:40 in the YT video)

Comment: You're putting all the data inside an `options` field, but that's not what the video says. If you look at timecode 9:35 you can clearly see that the object's structure is significantly different from yours. Try following the tutorial exactly first, before experimenting.

Comment: @ChrisG Ah dude, I completely missed that he wrote it all in data ! thanks !! and yeah checked chart.js I had to put a script in there, not like his but similar. Dude I think im just tired enough studying. Thanks alot for the help !!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks too ChrisG in the comment section I solved it. I had to use  above my title and I completely missed that the guy in the video had put everything above the option line.